# Woxblom DragListView Class not found Exception DragItemRecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I try to use DragListView found on https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView
I copied the package to my project, imported the file android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar to my project and added the file to my library in the build path.

At the moment my activity only sets the view:

```
public class CreateGameActivity extends ModuleSettingsActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_game);
    }
}
```

activity_create_game.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gameengine.CreateGameActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drag_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Running the application leads to the error:
03-04 15:43:30.201: E/AndroidRuntime(25082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.schockenpro/com.gameengine.CreateGameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragItemRecyclerView

I found out that usualy this is caused by the missing jar file. According to that problem I imported the jar files as described above, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that I added the library of the recyclerview in a wrong way (not the usual ones).

At 1st I created a library project from the recyclerview.jar (found in android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/recyclerview/libs) file by importing it as existing project.
2nd I added the library to my project, then the error is gone.

The usual way adding a jar did not work here.